# Utilizing Docker in Chat application

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

How would one implement a chat application when user clicks “Create new room” on the front end, from there the user can add a name to the room set password and set number of users can connect (let say 8) and once they click “create room” it creates that room in a container. Once the users are done with their chat session, the container is automatically deleted.

I am not asking on “help me with code”. I want to learn the topics that are necessary to learn in order to achieve my project. Please let me know!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You will need a container orchestrator to manage the container on the application. The most popular one is the [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/). It can be very hard to configure and use it and I highly recommend you using it in a cloud environement like Azure with [AKS](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/kubernetes-service/) or AWS (with [EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/)).

Scaling your application to have more container instances can depend of a lot of differents factors. You could configure it by request number, CPU/Memory/Network usage, etc. These configurations should be on the orchestrator side (kubernetes in case).

I never implemented something like this (adding new instances of my application by code) but I think it is possible with a SDK for the orchestrator. Take a look on this:
https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp